# Flutter: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: flutter, onesignal, flutter-ios, flutter2.0

After migrating to null-safety and flutter 2 I get problem with ios build:
I run `flutter clean; rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock; rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace;  flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart`

and got this logcat:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardTypedData", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardMessageCodec", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebasePlugin.o)
          objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(FLTGoogleMapsPlugin.o)
          objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(FLTGoogleMapTileOverlayController.o)
          objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapMarkerController.o)
          objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
          objc-class-ref in onesignal_flutter(OSFlutterCategories.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
          objc-class-ref in firebase_crashlytics(FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.o)
          objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
          objc-class-ref in onesignal_flutter(OSFlutterOutcomeEventsController.o)
          objc-class-ref in onesignal_flutter(OneSignalPlugin.o)
          objc-class-ref in onesignal_flutter(OSFlutterTagsController.o)
          objc-class-ref in onesignal_flutter(OSFlutterInAppMessagesController.o)
          ...
      "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
          -[FLTFirebaseCorePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
          -[FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_crashlytics(FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.o)
          ___61-[FLTTileProviderController requestTileForX:y:zoom:receiver:]_block_invoke in google_maps_flutter(FLTGoogleMapTileOverlayController.o)
          -[FLTGoogleMapController onMethodCall:result:] in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
          -[OSFlutterOutcomeEventsController handleMethodCall:result:] in onesignal_flutter(OSFlutterOutcomeEventsController.o)
          -[OneSignalPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in onesignal_flutter(OneSignalPlugin.o)
          -[OSFlutterTagsController handleMethodCall:result:] in onesignal_flutter(OSFlutterTagsController.o)
          ...
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[full log is here](https://gist.github.com/rovkinmax/9a9c509dd02943851e9f6118167190d5)

What I try and it did't help:

- `pod deintegrate && rm Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update`
- set up `platform :ios, '12.0'` in Podfile
- set up manually architectures in Build Settings as `arm64`

This problem I have on two flutter projects, but I have no idea how to fix it.

UPD:
It's look like a problem with OneSignal https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/389

UPD2:
sample project with problem https://github.com/rovkinmax/OneSignalSDKProblem

Comment: I'd also try recreating runner projects (iOS included) with flutter create .

Comment: Are you trying to run it on simulator, physical device, or archive?

Comment: are you trying to Run with M1 Device?

Comment: I try run it on simulator and physical device. And I'm using mac book with intel proc.

Comment: Also I created sample with problem https://github.com/rovkinmax/OneSignalSDKProblem

Comment: What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @tomerpacific 12.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution for this problem:

1. Set up selected configurations as None

[image]

2. Check that check box is turn on

[image]

More info [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/389) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78436)

Comment: didnt worked for me

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this problem and fixed with

**Build setting** -> search Valid Architecture:

Remove **armv7** from the list

If Xcode version > 12.0 Then go project or target -> **Build Settings** -> **Excluded Architecture**

Then Add **armv7**

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: Worked for me, but the value needs to be under the "Any IOS SDK" key inside Excluded Architectures